# Inherit child template to the parent template using Powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions, templates, inheritance

I have 2 templates:

- Template A: PersonalTemplate
- Template B: PrivateTemplate

Here I want to inherit Template B in Template A using the PowerShell script.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to set the Base template field (`__Base template`). Is that what you're hoping to do? If so, you should be able to find what you need here: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items#get-item-then-change-item-properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sitecore PowerShell has a function called [`Add-BaseTemplate`](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/add-basetemplate). This function can add one or more base templates to a template item.

There are multiple ways to call it, but the simplest is to get both template items and then pass those to the function:

```
Add-BaseTemplate -Item <Item> -TemplateItem <TemplateItem[]>
```

You can use that to add `Template B` to the base templates for `Template A` like this:

```
$templateB = Get-Item master:\templates\path\to\TemplateB
$templateA = Get-Item master:\templates\path\to\TemplateA

Add-BaseTemplate -Item $templateA -TemplateItem $templateB
```